# Adding object members to business entities in OOD

Tags: oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have 2 business entities (objects): Product and Order. The Product object contains a "Name" property in addition to some other properties. The Order entity contains "Id, Date ... etc" properties in addition to a property that points to Product (assuming that an order can have only one product for the sake of simplicity)

In my case, when I want to show a list of orders, I want to show the name of the product for each order but I don't need to show the other product's properties.

My question is, when I design the Order entity class, should I add a property that points to Product, or I should simply add a property called "ProductName"? And if the answer is to add a property that points to Product, is it ok to load only the Name property or I should fill all ther other properties as well (at the time of retrieving data from DB)?

I would also appreciate it if you can add links to some articles with your answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Although the answers didn't directly answer my question but they were eye openers on the issue. Thanks

Comment: but I have to select only one answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an assumption in your question that order-display thingie must be a 1-1 match with order entity.

I think you've dug a hole for your self with your attempt at simplifying to one product per order.

If you had a join table (OrderProducts? or better still OrderLines. Neither the Order nor the Product Entities would have to 'know' about each other. 
You could keep those clean and simple, and delegate this DisplayOrders function to the new Join Entity.

Perhaps if I pretend to be the customer and say I want the Orders Display to not show ProductName anymore and instead show the total order value.

That would be a lot of rejigging of your entities and if you kept with this 1-1 match idea, your db as well.

Don't go there. Change is a given.
ip
After the comments...

If it really is a 1- 1 relationship, then you don't need two entities. 1-1 would be one product per order, and one order per product.

I did foolishly assume given your question that in fact you can have a product ordered many times.

Most of the interesting methods (aside from basic crud on the two entities) are therefore based on the relationship(s) between the two entities. That's the part of the domain you should be modeling.

After more comments...

I never denormalise unless I am optimising for performance, and I do that 'last' if I have no better option.

In the case you are talking about needing one property off the dependent object I would either create entities on the fly, and put publisherid on the book entity.

I'd do that on the assumption, that the name property of the publisher entity could change. Denormalising would mean that I would have to capture a change to publisher name, read through all the books and change the name on them. Worse still there's a hidden assumption in there, that publisher name is unique. Now you could probably go with that, but in order to avoid a truly horrible bug should some booger of a user give two publishers the same name, you would have to enforce it.

In the real world outside of this deliberately constrained example, where I would expect there to be some functionality assigned to the pseudo entity BookListItem (e.g selecting it for a reading list or shopping cart), I'd be seriously tempted by a third first class entity BookListItem, and perhaps a fourth BookList.

All designs are compromises, if you are going to be looking at lists of books a lot, and publisher name is going to be a once in a blue moon operation and you are prepared for the identity issue, and you can foresee no change to this behaviour, then denormalising is a good compromise.

In some ways there is no right answer to your question, what you need to be clear about is what your design permits / enables and what constraints it imposes, e.g. PublisherName is unique, which is nowhere in the requirement and might cause your customer to call you various names....

HtHs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid that asking my question with Order and Product made the question misleading and not clear. Please try to re-read  again but instead of Order, replace it with "Book" and instead of Product, replace it with "Publisher"

Comment: One more note: please don't assume anything that is not listed in the question. The whole idea about my question is about when you have 2 DB tables with 1-1 relationship and how we need to represent them in classes. How should they reference each other in the classes?

Comment: If they have a 1-1 relationship, why two classes! There's an assumption in there isn't there. You might be better off on Programmers with this question. More of discussion now.

Comment: oh and depending on how you identify book, they can have more than one publisher...

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. It seems that in my attempt to make the question simple I have made it invalid/complicated :) I feel that I'm having a problems in making the question clear so you can answer it on the same time I feel that my question is quite simple. More explanation in the next comment

Comment: Let's say that you and I work in the same company and the management came and told me you have to develop a system that has the following features: We need to be add books. Every book has a title, ISBN, publishing date, and one publisher. We also need to add publishers and assign books to them and every publisher has a name, owner name, country name and date of establishment. We need to have a page with a list of books. Every row should contain the book title, ISBN, publishing date and publisher name.... to be continued in the next comment

Comment: One publisher can publish many books. The management came to you and told you that you need to review my design. I wrote the initial design and I provided you with 2 designs to select the best one. The first design has 2 classes: Publisher and Book. The publisher has the following properties: Name (string), OwnerName (string), CountryName (string), EstablishmentDate (DateTime). and the Book class has the following properties: Title (string), ISBN (string), PublishingDate (DateTime), PublisherName (string). To be continued in the next comment

Comment: The second design has 2 classes. the first class is Publisher and it is exactly the same as the one in the first design. The second class is Book and it contains the following properties: Title (string), ISBN (string), PublishingDate (DateTime), PublisherName (it is of type "Publisher") Now you want to give me advice on which one of the 2 designs I should follow and why

Comment: I'm sorry for making the question lengthy but I felt that briefing it made more harm than good. I'd like to thank you again for trying to help me :)

Comment: I know that you have started being mad on me :) I read the new paragraphs you added to your answer. The first part was about normalization/denormalization, and because my question is about OO design (not DB design) I don't think this is related to my question. I don't want to change the database design. The database design is simply 2 tables with 1-to-many relationship. and then you started talking about "BookListItem" and "BookList". Although adding these 2 classes can help in the overall design but I still this doesn't answer my question which is specifically about class "Book"

Comment: In general, I'm expecting that there would be no right answer to my question and it would always depend on the case and this is why I need some articles to read about this issue. I know I need to read a few articles on this topic to have a better understanding and then I will consequently answer myself. My problem is that I don't know where to find these articles and I don't know what is the name of this subject. I tried to search in google but could find sufficient information

Comment: Who told you normalisation was just databases? It's about data duplication and integrity. What goes for the tables in DB, also goes for your entities in memory. I would not add publisher-name to book, unless I knew the described deficiencies from doing that would never be an issue. This might help, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of CQRS . To show anything UI related, just have a query handler (service) getting the required view model data directly from the db (persistence), so the Business/Domain layer is skipped. And that's all. **You shouldn't design your business model based on UI needs**.

When dealing with changing the state of the business model (**Command** part of CQRS), the design should reflect the concepts and their relationships. In your case the Order *references* one or more Products using their Id. This model shouldn't be used for querying, only for create/update.

To query things, depending on your persistence implementation you can use the existing db data or a use case dependent read model created automatically (via domain events handlers) when the domain state changes (but this is a more complex case, it depends on proper domain events design, a message based architecture and a storage that can't easily be queried).